# Controller not inheriting before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

So I have ApplicationController.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def decode_email
    params[:email] = URI::decode(params[:email])
  end
end
```

and then UsersController.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :decode_email, only: [:show]

  def show
    #blah blah
  end
end
```

Now hitting the show action results in:

```
undefined local variable or method 'decode_email' for #<UsersController:0x007fb5f216a710>
```

Why isn't that method being inherited so it can be properly used as a before_filter?

Comment: This should work. Could it be that `decode_email` is mistakenly a private method? Do you have `private` somewhere in your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: It is not working exactly because of `private` - it should be private .

Comment: Which ruby and rails versions are you using? Did you try restarting your server?

Comment: @QumaraSixOneTour, no it SHOULDN'T be private! It should be either public or protected, but not private.

Comment: Looks like it should work, but maybe try adding `helper_method :decode_email` above the method in `ApplicationController.rb`.

Comment: **It works on clean app** for sure in case you described. So the problem is deeper and we need you Application and Users Controllers code to figure out the bug.

Comment: It is working OK for me, with public or private inherited methods... post your full controllers code to see if we find anything else.

Comment: working for me with private

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
    def decode_email
      params[:email] = URI::decode(params[:email])
    end
end
```

is working for me